# Is it possible to do this type of convert?

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime

I'm running this command as a process: net user useid /domain and my program display one specifed line, this line tells when the user wp expire and put it on a label. Label looks like this:Password Expires(13space)2022.02.12 3:43:02.I want to get the difference between this and the current date. Error:System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid.
How can I solve this?

```
while (!pw.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = pw.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                line = line.Replace(" ", "").Replace("Passwordexperies","");
                counter++;
                if (counter == 12)
                {
                    label2.Text = line;
                        break;
                }
                else
                {

                    label2.Text = "You aren't connected!";

                }
            }
            pw.WaitForExit();
Form_Load event
            label3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd H:mm:ss");
            DateTime pwcr = DateTime.Parse(label3.Text);
            DateTime pwexp = DateTime.ParseExact(label2.Text, "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss", null);
            TimeSpan t = pwexp - pwcr;
            string pwr = String.Format("{0} day, {1} horus, {2} minutes, {3} seconds",
            t.Days, t.Hours, t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
            label4.Text = pwr;
```

Comment: Change "HH" to "H".

Comment: Spell `Passwordexperies` correctly too, and double check the case; C# is case sensitive

Comment: If you are messing around with reading strings off command line outputs to get password expiry then you are doing this wrong. Either do it with a WMI or LDAP query, or use Powershell. That way you get it programatically as an actual date value, rather than parsing a string

Comment: For example in Powershell you can do `(Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'YourUserName'" -Properties "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"` (which you can call programmatically from C#) then shove the result into `DateTime.FromFileTime` to get an actual date